In Madame Wu’s experiment, why don’t we say the electrons are emitted opposite to applied magnetic field instead of saying opposite to their spin?
My understanding of the experiment is that if the magnetic field for example, is applied away from me, and so the orientation of the spins will also be away from me aligned to the magnetic field. Now let’s take a parity transformation, and after the transformation, the magnetic field would still point away from me, but now the spin orientation is towards me. And according to the interpretation of this experiment, it says that the electrons are emitted opposite to their spin, so in former scenario, the electrons are being ejected towards me, but after the transformation, since the spin direction is now towards me, so the electrons should get emitted away from me. As far as I understand this is creating a paradox. I am not sure if that’s why we say the parity is violated, but what if instead of saying the electrons are ejected opposite to their spin direction, we say the electrons are ejected opposite to the applied magnetic field? Because then there shouldn’t be any discrepancies in describing the direction in which the electrons are emitted. What is the correct explanation here?


Now let’s take a parity transformation, and after the transformation, the magnetic field would still point away from me, but now the spin orientation is towards me.

This is your mistake. Both the magnetic field and the spin orientation stay the same direction under mirror reflection. Instead, the linear momentum of the emission is the opposite.
If there is parity symmetry, the emission should be symmetric between "aligned with spin" and "opposite to spin". The experiment showed that there is violation of parity symmetry by weak interaction.
